# Unable to focus form element on modal open with react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, chakra-ui

I'm trying to solve a problem that seems quite straight forward. I want to focus a form element as soon as a modal opens.

Since `react-hook-form` does not provide a direct handle to the form refs, I'm trying to use a `useEffect` hook and `react-hook-form`s howngrown `setFocus` functions but I keep seeing the error:

> s.focus is not a function

**Code**

--> [Link to coding sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-platform-8ygcfq?file=/src/App.js:0-1150)

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import "./styles.css";
import {
  ChakraProvider,
  Modal,
  ModalOverlay,
  ModalContent,
  ModalHeader,
  ModalFooter,
  ModalBody,
  Button,
  ModalCloseButton,
  useDisclosure
} from "@chakra-ui/react";

export default function App() {
  const { setFocus, register } = useForm();
  const { isOpen, onClose, onOpen } = useDisclosure();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isOpen) return;
    setFocus("name");
  }, [setFocus, isOpen]);

  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      <div className="App">
        <Button onClick={onOpen}>Open</Button>
        <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
          <ModalOverlay />
          <ModalContent>
            <ModalHeader>Modal Title</ModalHeader>
            <ModalCloseButton />
            <ModalBody>
              <input {...register("name")} />
            </ModalBody>
            <ModalFooter>
              <Button colorScheme="blue" mr={3} onClick={onClose}>
                Close
              </Button>
            </ModalFooter>
          </ModalContent>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe setFocus can't run because the modal content (and the input inside) is first unmounted.

An easy solution using setFocus is to make the form as an independant component :

```
const Form = () => {
  const { setFocus, register } = useForm();

  useEffect(() => {
    setFocus("name");
  }, [setFocus]);

  return <input {...register("name")} />;
};
```

and then include it inside the modalBody.

[Fixed sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-http-84dv70?file=/src/App.js:840-911)

Answer (score 1):

Read the Chakra documentation there is one prop `initialFocusRef`, you can pass the ref to the element you want to focus on initially

```
Chakra provides 2 props for this use case:

initialFocusRef: The ref of the component that receives focus when the modal opens.
finalFocusRef: The ref of the component that receives focus when the modal closes.
```

```js
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import "./styles.css";
import {
  ChakraProvider,
  Modal,
  ModalOverlay,
  ModalContent,
  ModalHeader,
  ModalFooter,
  ModalBody,
  Button,
  ModalCloseButton,
  useDisclosure
} from "@chakra-ui/react";

export default function App() {
  const { setFocus, register } = useForm();
  const { isOpen, onClose, onOpen } = useDisclosure();

  const initialRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    //setFocus("name");
  }, [setFocus, isOpen]);

  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      <div className="App">
        <Button onClick={onOpen}>Open</Button>
        <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose} initialFocusRef={initialRef}>
          <ModalOverlay />
          <ModalContent>
            <ModalHeader>Modal Title</ModalHeader>
            <ModalCloseButton />
            <ModalBody>
              <input {...register("name")} ref={initialRef} />
            </ModalBody>
            <ModalFooter>
              <Button colorScheme="blue" mr={3} onClick={onClose}>
                Close
              </Button>
            </ModalFooter>
          </ModalContent>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}
```

**UPDATED BASED ON COMMENT**

By default, Chkra focus enabled elements if you just add `tabIndex` to your elements and give order value appropriately then it will get focused. Previously close button was focused by default, now in the below code you will notice I have given tabIndex=2 to the close button and tabIndex=1 to the input element and it is working as expected.

```js
<ChakraProvider>
      <div className="App">
        <Button onClick={onOpen}>Open</Button>
        <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
          <ModalOverlay />
          <ModalContent>
            <ModalHeader>Modal Title</ModalHeader>
            <ModalCloseButton tabIndex="2" />
            <ModalBody>
              <input tabIndex="1" {...register("name")} />
            </ModalBody>
            <ModalFooter>
              <Button colorScheme="blue" mr={3} onClick={onClose}>
                Close
              </Button>
            </ModalFooter>
          </ModalContent>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    </ChakraProvider>
```

If you want to use that using ref then you can check "[How to share ref usage?](https://www.react-hook-form.com/faqs/)", maybe it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I can not reset the `ref` on the element. The return value of `...register(...)` will contain a ref that `react-hook-form` needs to povide the form functionality. This can not be simply overwritten.

Comment: @Xen_mar I have updated my answer you can check. just add tabIndex to the close button and input element that will work

Answer (score 0):

A way is to add a timeout to focus after isOpen for modal is triggered.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isOpen) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setFocus("imageUrl");
      }, 50);
    }
  }, [isOpen]);
```